# To monitor changes in the properties of a class using reflection in C#

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a class with public properties. Example of a class.

```
public class Book
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}
```

To optimize queries, only modified fields must be sent to the database.

**How can I track changes to the properties of the book class, provided that I can't rewrite the code of the class itself in any way?**

The book itself is in the cache for updating, it can be accessed from outside the link.

I've been working on it for a week.

*I searched through the reference books on reflection, but I didn't find anything. Although you can somehow use reflection to read the set method of the book class, add your own code, and put everything back in the method.*

Comment: Why can't you rewrite this model?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework? (edit: made it an understandable question :p )

Comment: Reflexion can't help you to do that. You need to implement changes control in setters, or use the DataBindings framework. Since you say you can't improve the class code, I don't see what you can do... But the question is who manage entities ? The entities/database engine may help you.